# How to create in mongoose, if it exists, update it in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I have problem when I want create new model or if not exist, update it.

For example, I have data in a database:

```
{
        "unix": 1668380400,
        "type": "soup",
        "order": 1,
        "value": "Chicken"
    },
    {
        "unix": 1668380400,
        "type": "main",
        "order": 0,
        "value": "Gulash"
    },
    {
        "unix": 1668553200,
        "type": "soup",
        "order": 0,
        "value": "Asian"
    }
}
```

I want to get to the point that when unix and type and order are the same - modify the value. But if the element with the same unix, order and type is not found in the database - add a completely new record to the db.

I thought this was how I would achieve the desired state. But a mistake.

```
router.post("/add", async (req, res) => {
  const data = req.body;
  await data.map((el) => {
    const { unix, type, order, value } = el;
    Menu.findOneAndUpdate(
      { unix, type, order },
      { unix, type, order, value },
      { new: true, upsert: true }
    );
  });
  res.status(201).json({ status: true });
});
```

req.body:

```
[
    {
        "unix": 1668380400,
        "type": "main",
        "order": 2,
        "value": "Sushi"
    },
    {
        "unix": 1668553200,
        "type": "soup",
        "order": 0,
        "value": "Thai"
    }
]
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you please add how is your `req.body`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a solution. Everything works as it should, but wouldn't it be better to send the data with JSON.stringify() and then parse this data on the servers using JSON.parse()?

Another thing is the map method. Is it OK like this? Can't cause throttling?

```
router.post("/add", (req, res) => {
  const data = req.body;
  data.map(async (el) => {
    const { unix, type, order, value } = el;

    await Menu.findOneAndUpdate(
      { unix, type, order },
      { value },
      { upsert: true }
    );
  });
  res.status(201).json({ status: true });
});
```